# I lost the "global menu bar integration" firefox addon

Tags: firefox

I somehow lost the "global menu bar integration" firefox addon. Probably uninstalled it accidentally.

I have tried `dpkg-reconfigure` and also `apt-get remove firefox-globalmenu && apt-get install firefox-globalmenu`. But neither worked.

How do I get the add-on into Firefox addon?

I couldn't find an xpi file either, to point firefox manually to it for installation.

**Edit:** Found a fix on my own, see my comment to the answer that was mots helpful :) Thanks everyone for looking into this.

Comment: try `sudo apt-get purge firefox-globalmenu && sudo apt-get install firefox-globalmenu`.

Comment: Ah! Purged now. I have the PPA installed to use firefox-aurora (the next-next version of firefox) instead of the normal firefox. This means that there is no global-menu package in my list anymore :/ I could install `firefox-globalmenu` with the PPA disabled but APT complains that it wants firefox 15, not 17. Any chance to force-ignore this dependency check?

Comment: added an answer. tell me if it works.

Comment: This issue occurred once more quite recently. Disabling the addon and restarting firefox then re-enabling and restarting again solved it for me here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the `firefox-globalmenu` here: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/firefox/firefox-globalmenu_15.0.1+build1-0ubuntu0.11.04.1_amd64.deb

Install it by running:

```
sudo dpkg -i package.deb
```

Replace `package.deb` with the appropriate name.

Comment: `firefox-globalmenu depends on firefox (= 15.0.1+build1-0ubuntu0.11.04.1); however:`
  `Version of firefox on system is 17.0~a2~hg20120920r106901-0ubuntu1~umd1~precise.`
Essentially, what I was asking for is a way to override this warning.

Comment: try `sudo apt-get install --force-yes firefox-globalmenu`. If that doesn't work try `sudo apt-get install --ignore-missing firefox-globalmenu`.

Comment: That helped installing it, but I fixed it differently. I diabled the PPA and had to remove firefox completely; then installed firefox 15 which brought the globalmenu back. Then I upgraded to aurora (re-enabling the PPA).

Answer (score 2):

Navigate to about:config, search for 'unity', and toggle from true to false

Answer (score 0):

remove the new beta firefox :

`sudo apt-get remove firefox`

update your repository:

`sudo apt-get update`

then install latest stable firefox:

`sudo apt-get install firefox`
`sudo apt-get install firefox-globalmenu`

Comment: It's *not* a problem with aurora, the ppa works fine and brings its own firefox-globalmenu

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Firefox Aurora ( which is an unstable release) , sometimes you might get an update without the globalmenu package. The only thing you can do is to either wait for the new update from [Ubuntu Mozilla Daily Build Team](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-mozilla-daily/+archive/firefox-aurora) or remove the aurora ppa and install the stable release.